Помогите с хранимой процедруой на T-SQL в WindowsForms (ado.net)
У меня есть задание:

Осуществлять продажу изданий магазинам; Обеспечить наличие в одном заказе разных изданий в заданном количестве;

В первой части задания нужно осуществить прадажу изданий магазинам т.е у меня есть ComboBox в котором я выбираю покупателя (магазин) далее еще ComboBox для выбора издания (title) и другие ComboBox'ы. Далее по кнопке ПРОДАТЬ у меня выполняется процедура, которая заносит в таблицу sales эту самую продажу.
Хранимая процедура:
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertSalesOrder
    @stor_name VARCHAR(40),
    @title_name VARCHAR(80),
    @qty SMALLINT,
    @payterms VARCHAR(12)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @stor_id CHAR(4);
    DECLARE @title_id CHAR(6);
    DECLARE @ord_num VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @ord_date DATETIME;


    SET @ord_date = GETDATE();



    SELECT @stor_id = stor_id
    FROM stores
    WHERE stor_name = @stor_name;


    SELECT @title_id = title_id
    FROM titles
    WHERE title = @title_name;

    
    SET @ord_num = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()), 10);


    
    IF @stor_id IS NOT NULL AND @title_id IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO sales (stor_id, ord_num, ord_date, qty, payterms, title_id)
        VALUES (@stor_id, @ord_num, @ord_date, @qty, @payterms, @title_id);

       
        UPDATE titles
        SET ytd_sales = ytd_sales + @qty
        WHERE title_id = @title_id;

        
        SELECT 'Заказ успшно добавлен' AS [Result];
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @stor_id IS NULL
            SELECT 'Магазин с указанным названием донт найден' AS [Result];
        IF @title_id IS NULL
            SELECT 'Издание с указанным названием донт найдено' AS [Result];
    END
END

Форма приложения:

Но так же мне еще нужно выполнить вторую часть задания:

Обеспечить наличие в одном заказе разных изданий в заданном количестве;

В одном заказе обеспечить наличие нескольких изданий. Номера заказа ord_num(№ Задания) он у меня сам генерируется в процедуре.
Так вот как можно это сделать ? У меня была идея сделать так что бы при повторном нажатие на кнопку ПРОДАТЬ у меня выполнилась еще одна продажа и ее результат вывелось в DataGridView второй строкой, но при повторном нажатии уже будет не старый номер заказа, а новый сгенерированный.

Вы уже один и тот же вопрос задаёте, по-моему, четвёртый раз. И по-прежнему нет никакой информации о том, откуда берутся сведения, в частности, о потребных в заказе позициях и количествах. Так вот как можно это сделать ? Ну... вы онлайн-магазинами когда-нибудь пользовались? что такое "корзина" - знаете? Ну так вот это - одно из решений. Сперва всё, что надо - в корзину, а потом всё отмеченное галками в корзине - в заказ.

@Akina Привет! Этот вопрос я задаю второй раз в первый я не совсем подробно описал я думаю, можете пожалуйста подробнее рассказать как можно в процедуре сделать так что бы процедура работала как карзина. Или какой-нибудь материал?

@Akina Смотрите я хочу сделать так, в приложении я выбираю покупателя далее издание и нажимаю на кнопку ДОБАВИТЬ у меня генерируется номер заказа и в DataGrid вставляются информация по этому заказу, а потом я смогу добавить еще заказы при нажатие на кнопку ДОБАВИТЬ и в итоге при нажатие на кнопку ПРОДАТЬ в БД заносятся издания одного заказа. Вот так же можно сделать ни каких особо косяков нет ?

ни каких особо косяков нет ? Как по мне - есть. В такой схеме получается две различные процедуры для одного и того же действия - добавление позиции в заказ,- в зависимости от того, создан он или ещё нет. Считаю разделение на создание заказа и на добавление позиции в заказ (вне зависимости от того, первая она в нём или нет) более логичным.

@Akina я бы очень хотел понять это разделение на создание заказа и на добавление позиции в заказ (вне зависимости от того, первая она в нём или нет) Можете пожалуйста подробнее рассказать что вы имели ввиду ?
